# Potential energy in gravitation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

The gravitational potential energy of a two particle system is:

$$
U = -G \, \frac{m_1 \, m_2}{r}
$$

where $r$ is the distance between the two particles with mass $m_1$ and $m_2$, and the potential energy at infinite separation is taken to be zero.

My question is the following:

Is this the *sum* of the potential energies possessed by *each* particle?
If that is the case, then what would be the contribution of each particle to the total potential energy?

Comment: have a look here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/gpot.html

Comment: Potential energy between two masses is..... We know, but concept of energy depend on system so we cannot define your problem until you define what is your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The potential energy isn't possessed by either object. It is a property of the system of two objects and their interaction. If anything, I would say the potential energy is in the gravitational field.